# Keycloak-6.0.1 Custom Authenticator SPI

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm trying to implement a custom keycloack Authenticator SPI for authentication purposes against an external Datasource/Rest Service.  The plan is to migrate them into keycloak.

> > Updated the browser flow(copy and created a new flow and bind it).
> >
> > First time when the user logs in, will display custom theme login screen.
> >
> > On submit Using Custom SPI authenticate against external service.
> >
> > On success create users on the keycloak datasource.
> >
> > Create custom mappers to add extra user attributes on tokens.

I'm following section 8.3 of the official guide https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi_walkthrough, which is very similar to what I need.

Also, followed examples(https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/authenticator) I think the instructions doesn't map it to the new version.

For example:
In your copy, click the "Actions" menu item and "Add Execution". Pick Secret Question.

> > In Keycloak-6.0.1, there isn't any such execution as "Pick Secret Question".  I really don't need this, but I was atleast trying to set this flow to get hold on how the flow works.

Next you have to register the required action that you created. Click on the Required Actions tab in the Authenticaiton menu. Click on the Register button and choose your new Required Action.

> > There isn't such Register button on the required action.

Things I have done. 
Created new realm
Registered UI client
Created new user in new realm in keycloak tables. 
UI on login redirects to Keycloak UI and successfully authenticated and able to retrieve successfully tokens using javascript adapters

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
        keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(authenticated => {
            this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated })
        })
    }

....
....

if(this.state.keycloak) {
            if(this.state.authenticated) return (
                <div className="contact-body">
                 <p>Name: {this.state.name}</p>
                 <p>Email: {this.state.email}</p>
                 <p>ID: {this.state.id}</p>
               </div>
              );
      }
}
```

Would like to use Keycloak Login UI features(like OTP) along with custom authenticator SPI.  In the custom authenticator SPI get form fields like username and password and authenticate it using external service.  Then create users in Keycloak DB.

Can admin lock/temporarily suspend user within a realm in keycloak?

The other option, I am planning to use is, update login.ftl onsubmit to post username/password to custom service with keycloak url passed as query param.
Will validate it against custom service, create users on keycloak database and redirect to keycloak url which is passed on query param. This doesn't seem like right way.

Any help/thoughts will be highly helpful.

Comment: Hey Anthony, did you resolve it? could you share your code? I have the exact same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "User Storage SPI".  It would be the Section 11 on  [Keycloak Doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi)

Section 8, is needed if you need extra/custom authentication  like secret questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong SPI you are implementing.
For external datasource or service integration you must implement a custom **User Storage SPI**.